# How can i solve this pythagorean triplet problem?

Tags: pythagorean-triples

I came across this pythagorean triplet problem. According to which there is exactly one pythagorean triplet for which

```
a+b+c = 1000
```

**Pythagorean Triplet:**  a set of three natural numbers, a smaller than b smaller than c, for which,

```
a^2 + b^2 = c^2
```

for example:

```
3^2 + 4^2 = 9 + 16 = 25 = 5^2
```

**P.S:** I don't need exact solution, I just need some hint because I didn't find the triplet. Either it is smaller than 1000 or greater but not equal.

Comment: A primitive (gcd(a,b,c)=1) pythagorean triplet has $a=2uv$, $b=u^2-v^2$, and $c=u^2+v^2$ where exactly one of $u,v$ is even and gcd(u,v)=1. So 
 $a+b+c=2u^2+2uv=2u(u+v)=1000$...

Comment: This is Project Euler problem 9.  They request that you solve the problems yourself.  @JohnLou:  please delete the comment.

Comment: Sorry @RossMillikan, thanks for informing me.

Comment: @JohnLou:  Thanks.  I had a lot of fun with these.

Comment: @JohnLou Which topics in mathematics should I proceed with to learn all this?

Comment: @stevengregory what are these u and v that you mentioned. Which mathematic topics should I go through to learn all these.

Comment: Honestly? I just tried the first couple triples I know, and I got it. We know the triple $3, 4, 5$ has a sum of $12$. Can you find a triple with sum $60$, then? And then a few more educated guesses gets us to the right answer.

Comment: You can use [MathJax](https://goo.gl/OWv9nr) to format your posts.

Comment: @JohnLou I got the answer. it's 200, 375, 425. Thank you :)

Comment: @JohnLou - Note that I specified that exactly one of $u, v$ is even.

Comment: Oh, my mistake then.

Answer (score 0):

We know that $P=(m^2-n^2 )+2mn+(m^2+n^2 )=2m^2+2mn$

$$\text{We can find }(n,k)\text{ if we factor for  }n=\frac{P-2m^2}{2m}\text{ and let }m=\biggl\lceil\frac{\sqrt{P}}{2}\biggr\rceil\text{ to }\biggl\lfloor\sqrt\frac{P}{2}\biggr\rfloor$$

One problem with lower values of $m$ is that it results in $n>m$ and yield $2{nd}$ quadrant triples and/or multiples such as $f(6,215)=(-46189,2580,46261)$.

$$\text{In the case where }P=1000\qquad m_{min}=\biggl\lceil\frac{\sqrt{1000}}{2}\biggr\rceil=16\qquad m_{max}=\biggl\lfloor\sqrt\frac{1000}{2}\biggr\rfloor=22$$

We find that $m=20\Rightarrow n=5\Rightarrow f(20,5)=(375,200,425)$ which is a $25X$ multiple of $(15,8,17)$.